# How to use nested Recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

In my application I want use **RecyclerView** into another **Recyclerview** and for this I wrote below codes.

But after run application messed colors when scroll on items!

I have one RecyclerView for show products and into this RecyclerView I have onother RecyclerView for show colors!

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each colour `ViewHolder` has its own `RecyclerView`, right? It needs its own `ColorsAdapter` too - that's what you're using to tell a specific `RecyclerView` to display a specific set of colours.

Right now you have **one** adapter that you're reusing in all your `RecyclerView`s:

```
// top-level in SearchAdapter
lateinit var colorsAdapter: ColorsAdapter

// when binding a ViewHolder
colorsAdapter.setData(colors)
binding.itemsColors.setupRecyclerview(
    LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true),
    colorsAdapter
)
```

So any change you make to *that single adapter* will update every `RecyclerView` that's using it. And in that bind function, you call `setData(colors)` on that single adapter - you're basically updating everything to display those same colours.

---

Just like each `ViewHolder` has its own `RecyclerView` in the layout, you need it to have its own `ColorsAdapter` too. So you can just create one when each `ViewHolder` instance is created:

```
inner class ViewHolder(
    private val binding: ItemSearchListBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    // create a unique instance for this VH to use
    private val colorsAdapter = ColorsAdapter()

    ...
}
```

And now your `bind` function will refer to the VH's specific instance of the adapter (don't forget to delete the top-level one in `SearchAdapter` since you're not using it now). Also you'll have to work out how to make this work with whatever dependency injection you're doing.